# how to get response on http post method when post html data in ios?

Tags: ios

my code here...
not receive all html data....so plz reply me on it:sanandiyavipul@gmail.com

```
NSString *get_value_key=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"personen=%@&eigenaar=%@&soortwoning=%@&beveiliging=%@&soortdak=%@",[filter_ary4 objectAtIndex:[pickerView4 selectedRowInComponent:0]],[filter_ary7 objectAtIndex:[pickerView7 selectedRowInComponent:0]],[filter_ary8 objectAtIndex:[pickerView8 selectedRowInComponent:0]],[filter_ary9 objectAtIndex:[pickerView9 selectedRowInComponent:0]],[filter_ary10 objectAtIndex:[pickerView10 selectedRowInComponent:0]]];



NSData *postData = [get_value_key dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://media.komparu.com/inboedelverzekering/10045724/5193"]];


[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"text/html; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

// NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse =nil;

response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:nil];

NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[response1 bytes] length:[response1 length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
```

Comment: A single statement at 459 characters! Hint: Breaking up the statement and using intermediate statements and variables does no harm but does make the code comprehensible and debuggable.

Comment: Don't set "Content-Length", let the class set it for you.

Comment: how to breaking up statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the response it is in the variable: `urlResponse`.

If you want the html status code cast the response to `NSHTTPURLResponse` and access the `statusCode` property.

Or just create `NSHTTPURLResponse` instead of `NSURLResponse` and access directly.

```
NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse;
response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
NSInteger statusCode = urlResponse.statusCode;
NSLog(@"statusCode: %i", statusCode);
if (response1) {
    // process data
}
else {
    // Log the response and error description
    NSLog(@"urlResponse: %@", urlResponse);
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: bt how to get data after the post request ,post method not proper work?same error here

Comment: The data is returned by the `sendSynchronousRequest` method, in this case in `response1` unless there was an error. If  `response1` is nil then there was an error and it is described in the `error` and `urlResponse`  parameters *that you are ignoring* and the `statusCode` will contain the http error code. The problem is that you are ignoring both. Se the answer update for how to implement error handling.

Comment: thx zaph....bt wnevr change the value of get_value_key and response is same here response is same not change ,so wnevr i change value of get_value_key then response data is change bt here some mistake plz find out.....thx

Comment: It is up to yopu to change yout code to add the error checking and add the log results to your question. If we can't see the error we can't help.